# Don't Play With Me, Riley

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, affix-riddle

> My suffix’s prefix’s prefix’s suffix
> My prefix’s suffix’s suffix’s prefix
> My infix’s prefix’s suffix’s infix
> Don’t play with me

Who am I?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> My suffix’s prefix’s prefix’s suffix

> The end of me is the end of the first half of *p**re**fix*.

> My prefix’s suffix’s suffix’s prefix

> The start of me is the start of the second half of *suf**f**ix*.

> My infix’s prefix’s suffix’s infix

> The middle of me is the middle of the second half of *pref**i**x*.

> Don’t play with…

> fire.

Comment: Your answer's prefix is perfect's prefix. Your answer's suffix is perfect's suffix.

Comment: OK, that's pretty impressive @cap. It makes complete sense.